# Unable to use an external javascript .js file

Tags: javascript, html

This might sound stupid, but actually I'm trying to use an external hide.js javascript file inside another myfile.html file. Here are the simple codes:

myfile.html:

```
<html>
<script src="hide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

hide.js:

```
function fun()
{
    document.write("Hello!");
}
```

I have saved both files in the same folder.
The problem is, when I run the myfile.html, it should display "Hello!". But it doesn't display anything. Where's is the problem?

Comment: Your script defines the function `fun()` but never actually calls it.

Comment: view the browser console for errors in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just display the message without using the function in your hide.js file

myfile.html

```
<html>
 <script src="hide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

hide.js

```
document.write("Hello!");
```